# eth_rlp: AttributeError: module 'rlp' has no attribute 'Serializable'

Tags: python, brownie

Brownie won't initialise. Even after clearing paths, pipx, installing new versions.

Answer (score 1):

The error was actually with eth_rlp lib. Simple uninstall and installation of the latest version of eth_rlp worked.

Answer (score 0):

For when reinstalling eth-rlp is not enough:

You may have multiple installed python packages named `rlp`.

Here are a few possibilities:

1. rlp
2. eth-rlp (the one we want)
3. simple-rlp

You need to uninstall the others besides `eth-rlp`.